# How to get version number of Chromium based WebView programmatically in android?

Tags: android, webview

I want to access the version number of chromium based webview, is it possible to get that programmatically?

Any pointer around this will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
 new WebView(context).getSettings().getUserAgentString();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo("com.google.android.webview", 0);
            Log.d(TAG, "version name: " + pi.versionName);
            Log.d(TAG, "version code: " + pi.versionCode);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Android System WebView is not found");
        }


        WebView webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
        String useragent=webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();

        Log.e(TAG, "useragent: " + useragent);
```