# How to notify users who are getting specific crashes as seen in Android Vitals

Tags: android, crash, android-notifications, google-play-console, android-vitals

Many of my app users are getting the crash - [base.apk!libmonochrome.so] SIGTRAP
There is already question for this exact problem - [app-crashed-with-base-apklibmonochrome-so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66361472/app-crashed-with-base-apklibmonochrome-so)
and the possible resolution is to notify users to update their Android web view and chrome https://support.google.com/android/thread/103561027?hl=en

My question now is - Is there way to only notify users who have got this specific crashes as reported by vitals?

[image: Play console vital screenshot showing the crash events]

Answer (score 0):

The only way to notify the users that are affected by a specific crash is to be able to detect (or predict) the crash itself.

In this case you can try to detect what is the version of the chrome webview being used, and notify the user if it matches the version(s) that you know that has the bug.
To get the webview version check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668311/how-to-get-version-number-of-chromium-based-webview-programmatically-in-android).